# Check RSA encryption via public key: command-line vs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

I have done some search, both here and on the web, but apparently it seems to be difficult to find a similar issue around, so I decided to post a question here.

I have the following task to accomplish (and unfortunately I am not an expert in OpenSSL encryption), having the following ingredients:

- a SQL Server database (where I have 'sa' access rights, if necessary);
- a DER certificate with a public key only.

I am requested to encrypt some DB data using that public key, and the result of the encryption must be the same I would obtain by using the following command (it uses the PKCS#1 v 1.5 padding, if I understood well):

```
.\openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey <public key cert> -certin -pkcs
```

I know that SQL Server can import a certificate and encrypt data, but I don't know how/if I can set any options to drive the encryption process (e.g.: which padding it should use) in order to make sure that I really reproduced the  template I was given.
On the other hand, if I am not wrong, since I have *no* private key, then I cannot test my encryption by just encrypting some data via SQL Server and then de-crypting them via the `openssl` command.

As an alternative, I thought that a check method could consist in encrypting the same data via `openssl` and via SQL Server, and then check if the returned strings are the same. Unfortunately, I learned from another StackOverflow question the every time a data is encrypted it is applied some random padding which cause the encrypted string to be always different.
Then, the first question: is it possible, both in the `openssl` command and in SQL Server, to temporarily *'fix'* the used random seed, in order to make sure that every time one encrypts a string, it will always be applied the same padding, in order to be able to compare the results?

As an alternative, I would try to do my tests with a test certificate which I could try to generate with a pair of keys, but in this case I have some silly questions:

1. how can I generate a pair of keys and then create a certificate with the public key which will be an analogue to the one I was provided by the entity I will have to send data to?
2. how can I make sure that the format of this 'test' certificate is compliant to that of the production certificate provided to me?

Thanks a lot for every help and best regards. Sorry if my question can appear silly, but I am not an expert in this topic.